# Insert multidimensional array into mysql database with each array as mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

Need to  insert PHP array into mysql database as each array as column.

```
$test_array = array((1,2,3),(test1,test2,test3));
```

And output like

```
1   test1

2   test2

3   test3
```

UPDATE

```
foreach($test_array AS $test){
              $info_item = array(
                  "name"   => $test[0],
                  "name1"   => $test[1],
               );   
  $id = $fun_obj->insert($info_item,'test_table');
}
```

like this inserting each array as row.but i need each array as column

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider the [following article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get some help.

Comment: Please add the code you use for that and specify the problem you have with it.

Comment: You just need a loop for your array to insert it's not that hard. What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes i tried.using loop each array inserting as new row.i need each array as coulmn

Comment: I don't understand your latest comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$test_array = array(
                    array(1,2,3),
                    array('test1','test2','test3')
                   );

$new_array = array_map(null, $test_array[0], $test_array[1]);

print_r($new_array);

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => test1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => test2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => test3
        )

)
```